# Correct way to represent acquaintance enforced by interface in UML class diagram

Tags: c#, interfaces, uml, class-diagram

Suppose I have the following client code:

```cs
using System;

namespace InterfaceCompositionUml 
{
   internal class Program
   {
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {      
         MyInterfaceImpl x = new MyInterfaceImpl();
         MyClass y = new MyClass();
         x.MyProperty = y;

         Console.WriteLine(x.MyProperty.A);
      }
   }
}
```

The implementation of the various components is as follows:

## `MyClass`

```cs
using System;

namespace InterfaceCompositionUml 
{
   public class MyClass
   {
      public string A => "Hello";
   }
}
```

## `MyInterface`

```cs
using System;

namespace InterfaceCompositionUml 
{
   interface MyInterface
   {
      MyClass MyProperty { get; set; }
   }
}
```

## `MyInterfaceImpl`

```cs
using System;

namespace InterfaceCompositionUml 
{
   public class MyInterfaceImpl : MyInterface
   {
      public MyClass MyProperty { get; set; }
   }
}
```

I'm a bit stumped on how to represent the relationship between `MyClass` and `MyInterface`/`MyInterfaceImpl` in a class diagram following the UML 2 standard. There are two options that I can think of. Either `MyInterface` has an acquaintance with `MyClass`:

[image]

OR `MyInterfaceImpl` has an acquaintance with `MyClass`:

[image]

Which one is correct and why? If neither are correct then what is the correct representation?

Comment: The first one, because the interface explicitly mentions the type MyClass. It's explicitly referenced by the interface. The realization (implementation) arrow also means that the implementation class *inherits* all the members of the interface, and therefore, any relationships. The second diagram would imply that the interface has nothing to do with MyClass (and so, that the MyClass reference is meant to be implementation-specific, and invisible to clients that use MyInterface).

Comment: @FilipMilovanović: why not putting this comment into an answer, so the OP accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### In short

Both diagrams are correct but none of them is complete. The first would nevertheless be the way to go, as it a better insight into the design intention.  Indeed, in UML you are not obliged to show everything in a diagram and you are allowed to focus on what you think is more important:

- Showing the association at the interface level is sufficient:  readers can guess the missing but implicit association at interface implementation level (if it wouldn't be there, the interface implementation would not be compliant with the interface).
- Showing the interface at the implementation level is correct, but readers cannot guess the missing association at interface level, which seems more important for the design (which aims at decoupling the abstraction from the implementation).

*(By the way, "aquaintance" is pre-UML terminology and is somewhat confusion.  The term "association" should be preferred as it is precisely defined in the ISO and OMG official specifications.)*

### All the details

In your design there is an association between `MyInterface` and `MyClass`, and `MyInterfaceImpl` realises the interface. This can be shortly expressed as:

[image]

Considering that the property ensures efficient navigation at runtime between instances of `MyInterface` to their linked instances of `MyClass`, you can show the association as navigable, using an open arrow head on the `MyClass` side.

Now, in [C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/interface) an interface is only a contract with which its implementations need to comply with. This is why you need to repeat the property definition in the class definition.  In UML, interfaces have exactly the same semantic. Their realization does not mean that you inherit  from the interface. In principle you should find back at the implementation level all the elements defined in the interface.  So if you want to be complete, it should be:

[image]

*Remark that UML allows a notation, where there is a realisation arrow from the association with `MyInterfaceImpl` to the association with `MyInterface` since the one realises the other.  However this notation is not well known, and entry level tools such as plantuml do not support.*

Comment: Thanks for your time and valuable insight.